# Motion tracking and adding plain images

Tags: tracking

I found a tutorial on how to do what I want, except that I don't want any 3d mess.  I've got the path, and it's tracking a point nicely, but all I need now is to add an image to move it with the tracking path. How do I do that? Is such a simple thing even possible here?

You know, make the movement of the tracked path a XY movement of an image in VSE.

Comment: You can only use the tracking info in the VSE for stabilising a clip. If you want to add a tracked image to a  video without using 3D then you will have to use the compositor. There you can access the tracker data directly for translate effects.

Comment: Could you explain more please? I already stumbled upon it, but I've no clue whether that will do and what to do